# Дополнительное tty устройство

Tags: qt, c++, linux

Есть задание надо: создать дополнительное tty устройство, что бы при запуске приложение оно появлялось в системе и к нему подключалась другая программа.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать программно.

Comment: Круто, однако

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо всем, более правильный ответ на мой вопрос.
-pseudo-terminal
Как создать и работать с ним [вот](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/posix_openpt.html)

Comment: Обычно в таких случаях говорят о pty. Что-то не догадался, что именно они Вам нужны.

Answer (score 1):

mknod, но аргументы надо где-то в описаниях системы искать.

ls -l /dev говорит, что их много и major у всех 4. Похоже (по времени), что они создаются при загрузке ОС. 
Я, откровенно говоря, не понимаю с чем они на моей виртуалке связаны.

Почитайте man 2 mknod, man 4 ttyS, man 4 tty и SEE ALSO в них. Может что-то полезное найдете.